# Why is Stack Exchange attempting to use Flash Player?

Tags: support

On various Stack Exchange sites, I've had notifications telling me that the site was attempting to use Adobe Flash Player. I'm assuming that this is an advertisement on the page, but right now, I am not certain on what is trying to use Flash Player.

[image: Flash Popup]

Comment: Try accessing through https - if you do not see this again, it means someone is inserting flash content into the page. This could be your ISP, some maleware or anyone between you and the Stack Exchange servers.

Comment: You might want to check the network tab of the developer console in your browser, to see if you can find the URL of whatever flash object is attempting to be loaded. Might shed some light on the situation. We don't allow Flash from our advertising partners and don't use it for anything ourselves.

Comment: @Oded I did that and this happened: http://i.imgur.com/zTL17I7.png

Comment: @animuson I'm reloading the page, but I'm unable to reproduce the expected results

Comment: @Spammy23 That's a different error, because our Community Ads rotation script is loading from HTTP over an HTTPS connection.

Comment: This (the new error over https) *might* be due to a couple of ads that we serve not loading via https. Feel free to not load the unsafe scripts.

Comment: Probably a [similar issue with an ads on SO](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/342481/pycharm-ad-uses-flash), and it's hard to repro.